# please help me figure out what's wrong in my code

Tags: jquery

I faced a problem like; I placed a text box beside the calender but when I select the date from the calender it is not showing up in the test box .. 
Can anyone please help me out from this problem .. I need something like; when I select the date, month or an year in the calender beside it will show in the text box beside it ..

**UPDATE:**

Copied from the OP's comment:

```
<script language="javascript" src="includes/cal2.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript" src="includes/cal_conf2.js"></script> 

<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
    <input type="text" name="firstinput" size=20> 
    <a href="javascript:showCal('Calendar1')">Select Date</a>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
    <td class="heading2">&nbsp;</td>  
    <td align="center" valign="middle"></td>  
    <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>  
    <td align="center" valign="middle" colspan="2">
    <label></label>
```

Comment: We will need an actual piece of source code to be able to help you...

Comment: can you provide code that you already have/had so we can see the error?

Comment: What's your existing code look like?  It'll be better for you to learn if we help modify your existing code so you can see where you went wrong than if someone posts a new solution not based on your original idea.

Comment: and fix your title.  something more specific will get better answers, and help google index this question for other developers :)

Comment: Here goes the code for you guys : 

<script language="javascript" src="includes/cal2.js">

</script>
<script language="javascript" src="includes/cal_conf2.js"></script>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

AND

<td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="firstinput" size=20>  <a href="javascript:showCal('Calendar1')">Select Date</a>
      </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="heading2">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="center" valign="middle"></td>
     <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="center" valign="middle" colspan="2"><label>
       
     </label>

Comment: Edit your question and paste your code in there instead of as a comment. Use the formatting guide [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your code.

Comment: @kevin: looks like we'll need more code before we can figure this out, since the JavaScript is almost completely hidden within those files.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one thing you can do, you could always check out the jQuery website:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('#DateControl').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { $("#TextBoxControl").val(dateText); }
});
```

Comment: This is my code :

<script language="javascript" src="includes/cal2.js">

</script>
<script language="javascript" src="includes/cal_conf2.js"></script>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

AND

<td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="firstinput" size=20>  <a href="javascript:showCal('Calendar1')">Select Date</a>
      </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="heading2">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="center" valign="middle"></td>
     <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="center" valign="middle" colspan="2"><label>
       
     </label>